# How can I stop a ListBox's ItemsSource from being cleared when its binding source becomes null?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

**Background:**

Consider this XAML snippet:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid
        Grid.Row="0"
        x:Name="dataGrid"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Bobs}"
        >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Name"
                Binding="{Binding Name}"
                MinWidth="75"
                />       
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>   
    <ListBox
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="listBox"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Regions}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        >
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListBoxBehaviors:SynchronizeSelectedItemsBehavior Selections="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.SelectedRegions}"/>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Let's say I have a separate control that, when toggled, sets the Grid's IsEnabled property to false. Doing that has the effect of disabling the DataGrid and ListBox controls within the grid.

In .NET 4.0, an unfortunate side-effect of disabling a DataGrid is that the [DataGrid unselects all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610967/wpf-datagrid-retain-selection-when-disabling), so its SelectedItem is lost. This has the side-effect of firing the ListBox's ItemsSource binding, causing the ItemsSource to be cleared since the dataGrid's SelectedItem has become null.

**Question:**

How can I alter the binding, or change my XAML, so that when the dataGrid's SelectedItem becomes null, the ListBox's items collection isn't cleared.

**Addendums:**

1. I realize that the unselect DataGrid behavior was removed in .NET 4.5 but upgrading isn't an option right now.
2. I know there are solutions to circumventing the unselect DataGrid behavior; I want to know if it's possible to resolve my problem without using them.

Comment: can you store your selected items references in some temporary location if datagrid is disabled?

Comment: I have considered solutions where I cache the SelectedItem and restore it later. The problem is that when the SelectedItem becomes null, the ItemsSource binding is cleared. So while I can restore the SelectedItem after that, it's already too late.

Comment: just a thought, cant you avoid the disabling of datagrid. You can make the grid cells as readonly by firing some trigger..

Comment: In the application that the above snippet represents, the DataGrid does need to be disabled.